# Making text blink a certain number of times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make this blinking text stop after 3 seconds (or 3-5 blinks). I've set the blink rate to about the right speed, but cannot figure out how to make it stop.

Here's the code:

```
$('.blink').each(function() {
var elem = $(this);
setInterval(function() {
    if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }    
}, 200);
});
```

Any suggestions?

I've compiled a jQuery fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/M4Fcd/173/

Comment: Use `<blink>`?......just kidding :)

Comment: use jquery pulsate
http://api.jqueryui.com/pulsate-effect/ 
you can change speed/effect/style/ all that stuff..
`elem.effect( "pulsate", {times:5}, 3000 );`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

setInterval goes on indefinitely - or until stopped.

What you need to do is capture the intervalID when you create the interval and then clear the interval after you are done with it

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function....);

// when done
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

In your particular case:

```
$('.blink').each(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  // count the blinks
  var count = 1;
  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
        // increment counter when showing to count # of blinks and stop when visible
        if (count++ === 3) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    } else {
        elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }    
  }, 200);
});
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M4Fcd/186/

Comment: Very precise approach and easy to manage! It's great to know it won't end invisible-- probably should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: I updated the fiddle and the answer to only count visibles, so that you can say 3 blinks and it will be consistent regardless if it starts hidden or visible

Answer (score 6):

You could also use fadeIn/fadeOut like this

```
$('.blink').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.fadeOut(100)
        .fadeIn(100)
        .fadeOut(100)
        .fadeIn(100)
        .fadeOut(100)
        .fadeIn(100);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Fcd/177/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.blink').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else {
            elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }    
    }, 200);
});


setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
}, 3000)
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M4Fcd/176/

Answer (score 3):

I think I have the shortest answer.

```
function blinkElement(elm, interval, duration) {

    elm.style.visibility = (elm.style.visibility === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden");

    if (duration > 0) {
        setTimeout(blinkElement, interval, elm, interval, duration - interval);
    } else {
        elm.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

To blink for 3 seconds in the rate of 200 milliseconds.

```
blinkElement(element, 200, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ok, there is better way**. You can just toggle css class with *visibility: hidden*, the code gets simpler and than if you want to stop when visible/not visible just need to check with *hasClass*.

```
$('.blink').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this),
        timer = 0,
        interval = 200,
        stopAfter = 3000,
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            elem.toggleClass('blink');
            if(timer > stopAfter && !elem.hasClass('blink')) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
            timer += interval;
        }, interval);
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M4Fcd/183/

---

Now you can stop it when it's visible or not, but the idea is pretty the same.

```
$('.blink').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this),
        timer = 0,
        interval = 200,
        stopAfter = 3000;
    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
            if(timer > stopAfter) {
                clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            }
        } else {
            elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
        timer += interval;
    }, interval);
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M4Fcd/180/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var i = 0;
var blink;
$('.blink').each(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  blink = setInterval(function() {
      if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
          elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
          i++;
          if(i >= 3){
              clearInterval(blink);
          }
      } else {
        elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      }    
   }, 200);
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Fcd/182/)